# Python "if" statement changes variable value

Tags: python

This code is from a beginning python book I'm studying, the chapter is discussing Dictionaries.

```
favorite_languages = { 
    'jen': 'python',
    'sarah': 'c',
    'edward': 'ruby',
    'phil': 'python',
    }

friends = ['phil','sarah']

for name in favorite_languages.keys():
    print(name.title())

    if name in friends:
        print(" hi " +name.title() +
            ", i see your favorite language is " +
            favorite_languages[name].title() + "!")

The result is:

Jen 
Ed 
Phil 
 hi Phil, i see your favorite language is Python! 
 hi Sarah, i see your favorite language is C!
```

I'm having trouble understanding the logic of the code relative to the varible "name" and why the value changed. Meaning, the variable "name" is created by the "for" loop and all the Dictionary keys are stored in it, so that when the "if" statement begins the value of "name" is all keys.

My understanding of the "if" statement is that it just returns a boolean value of true or false, in this case true. But why does the value of "name" (as a result of this "if" statement) get changed to the value of "friends" at this point?

Is it just a rule that is built into Python? Because it does not logically follow, unless I'm missing something.

It would make more sense to me to write it:

```
if friends in name:
    print(" hi " friends.title() +
```

Comment: It doesn't and I can't understand why you think it does. And no, `name` is not "all the keys" - it is defined by the for loop, and takes the value of *each* item in the dictionary in turn - as demonstrated by the first `print()`. It is not modified by the if statement.

Comment: 'All the dictionary keys' are not stored in name, name takes on the value of each key one at a time. Maybe you should try for loops with a simpler example because it seems you do not yet understand how they work.

Comment: The output doesn't match the code.

Answer (score 1):

"...the variable "name" is created by the "for" loop and all the Dictionary keys are stored in it,"

I think that's your misconception. The line `for name in favorite_languages.keys():` does not store all the keys in the variable `name`. It means, for for each entry in the keys, execute the following code (the "suite"), one at a time, with the variable `name` set to a different entry each time.

So if `favorite_languages.keys()` is `['jen', 'sarah', 'edward', 'phil']`, execute the suite four times: once with `name` set to 'jen'; once with it set to 'sarah', once with it set to 'edward' and once with it set to 'phil'.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

to the *keys* in the dictionary is assigned the identifier `name` in the for loop, the *key* is the string before the `:` in a dictionary

```
favorite_languages = { 
'jen': 'python',
'sarah': 'c',
'edward': 'ruby',
'phil': 'python',
}

friends = ['phil','sarah']

for name in favorite_languages.keys():
    print(name.title())

    if name in friends:
        print(" hi " +name.title() +
            ", i see your favorite language is " +
            favorite_languages[name].title() + "!")
```

so the for-loop iterates through any key in the dictionary and prints its value with the `title()` method

in addition the `if`-statement determines if the key ( = name ) is existent in the list `friends`, if this is true it executes the linked code, if it is false it doesn't

the exact output is

```
Sarah
 hi Sarah, i see your favorite language is C!
Edward
Jen
Phil
 hi Phil, i see your favorite language is Python!
```

- for-loop greps key 'Sarah', if-statement checks if it is in list friends : is true so print
- for-loop greps key 'Edward', if-statement checks if it is in list friends : is false so no print
- for-loop greps key 'Jen', if-statement checks if it is in list friends : is false so no print
- for-loop greps key 'Phil', if-statement checks if it is in list friends : is true so print

in the dictionary the value that is associated with a key is accessed with `[key].title()`, in this case `[name].title()` because `name` is used as identifier for the keys